# Show that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| > \delta$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Use the Boundedness Theorem to show that if the function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| > \delta$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

The Boundedness Theorem is stated as such in our notes: A continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded and attains its bounds.

I understand what the question is saying, I just have no idea how to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

"It attains its bounds" means that there is a minimum value that $|f(x)|$ attains.
Because $f$ is continuous, we know that $|f|$ is continuous. Hence $|f|$ attains minimum and maximum values.

As $f(x)\neq 0$ for any $x$, this means that $|f(x)|\neq 0$ for any $x$. Thus $\inf|f(x)| = \min|f(x)| > 0$. Now you can just set $\delta = \min|f(x)|/2$.

Comment: Would I have to prove anything further or would this suffice as my solution. i.e. Setting, δ=min|f(x)|/2, we have shown there exists δ>0 s.t. |f(x)|>δ for all x∈[0,1]. This seems okay in my head but surely it can't be that easy! lol

Comment: If you want to be more explicit, you can say consider $s = \max\{f(x) : f(x) < 0\} = \sup\{f(x) : f(x) < 0\}$ and $t = \min\{f(x): f(x) > 0\} = \inf\{f(x): f(x) > 0\}$. Then $\min|f(x)| = \min\{|s|, |t|\}$. The "boundedness theorem" tells you that the infimum is in fact a minimum and the supremum is in fact a maximum, so they must be non-zero. I don't think you need to write anything more than I did in the answer though.

Comment: I think the answer is better without the previous comment, as it is not clear why the infimum of the restricted function would be attained. It’s simpler to say that “absolute value” is continuous and composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Yeah I was just editing my answer as you made that comment :)

Comment: You need intermediate value theorem to prove that $f(x)\neq 0$, right?

Comment: That's given as an assumption

Comment: Not as it is stated. The statement just claims that continuous image of segment is contained in segment, not that it is connected.

Comment: "..if the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x)\neq 0$ for all  $x\in[0,1]...$"

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, for some reason I misread that as $f(x)\neq x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested it can be proved by an argument of absurdity too:

Let assume the negated statement: " $\forall \delta>0, \exists x\in[0,1]\text{ s.t. } |f(x)|\le \delta$ "

In particular for any $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists $x_n\in[0,1]$ such that $|f(x_n)|\le \frac 1n$.

$(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $[0,1]$ compact, so we can extract a convergent subsequence $x_{\phi(n)}\to a$ with $a\in[0,1]\quad$ ($\phi\nearrow$ strict.).

Since $f$ is continuous then $f(a)=0$

which contradicts with the requirement that $f(x)\neq 0,\forall x\in[0,1]$.